# Flutter - Are SVGs bad for performance?

Tags: flutter, performance, svg, flutter-layout

I have a lot of logos that I want to use in my Flutter app at various resolutions, so am considering using the flutter_svg package to facilitate this.

I don't know much about SVGs are rendered compared to a regular image, so am wondering wether heavy use of `SVGPicture().asset` will have a tangibly affect my app's performance?

By heavy use, I mean up to ~12 SVGs on screen at one time.

Comment: are u using a  assets or network image

Comment: Only assets at the moment

Comment: SVG images are generally used in high pixel density image applications. Jpg images for standard .